# Issue on Posting Image to a PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to capture a highcharts chart and POST it to a PHP file
(result.php). I am able to capture image right now but I do not know how to POST captured image to another file. so far I have this code which is returning a PNG image

```
function postChart(chart) {
        var obj = {},chart;
        obj.svg = chart.getSVG();
        obj.type = 'image/png';
        obj.async = true;
        exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: exportUrl,
            data: obj,
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function (data) {
                // How to Send Image to result.php
            },
            error: function(data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

and this result.php file as:

```
<?php
    $content = $_POST['Not Sure What!'];
    echo  $content;
```

Now can you please let me know what can I put in

> success: function (data) {
>
> ```
>                 // How to Send Result to another Page
>             },
> ```

to post the image to result.php and how should I modify the result.php. Thanks

Comment: Try `$_FILE`instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: Hi pc-shooter, can you please let me know where should I use the $_FILE? and again how should I File to result.php

Comment: Set `cache:true` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the highchart's [exportChart API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart) Like

```
function postChart(chart) {
    chart.exportChart({
                       url : 'path/to/result.php',
                       type: 'image/png',
                       filename: 'my-chart'
                     });
}
```

Then from result.php you will be able to access the $_POST variable. which will contain following array, where `$_POST['svg']` is the image in svg format.

```
array (
  'filename' => 'my-chart',
  'type' => 'image/png',
  'width' => '0',
  'scale' => '2',
  'svg' => '',
)
```

You can then use the highchart's [server side script](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server/) to convert the image from svg to your desired format.

If you do not like to use java library for the conversion, you can also try [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5334-PHP-Render-a-SVG-graphic-as-a-PNG-image.html)

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Hi xiidea, thanks for you comment. but can tou please explain this a a little more? where should I use the  function postChart() is this sitting instead of the ajax()?

Comment: @Behseini: I thought this section you have already implemented!! I have just rewrite your function using the highchart's api. You can just replace your postChart with this version, and call similarly

Comment: Ok I have a chart running perfectly but where should I use the postChart() function?

Comment: When do you plan to submit the image to your result.php? @Behseini

Comment: Yes your js implementation is perfect, you just need to set `'path/to/result.php'` to actual path to your `result.php`, then implement the server side code as suggested in reference links. @Behseini

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51543/discussion-between-behseini-and-xiidea)

Answer (score 0):

This works only if your php-script is somewhere on `http://export.highcharts.com/`

(Because you set the `crossDomain` property to `true`)

In your ajax method:

Change:

```
data: obj,
```

TO:

```
data: {
 objName: obj,
}
```

Then in the result.php:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES['objName']);
    // If you're interested, what else is inside $_FILES
    var_dump($_FILES);
```

Comment: Thanks pc-shooter, same thing happens as Ehsan's solution. I am loosing the image in case of changing the data: obj,

Comment: I did, still  no image!

Comment: And your `obj` contains something?

Comment: I just asked one question! does this looks like two?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51541/discussion-between-pc-shooter-and-behseini)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking. This may be of some help though.

When working with files on upload use `$_FILES`. Its exactly like `$_POST` but for files.

Theres a selection of variables you can gather from the file using `$_FILES`.

```
<? 
$tempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
?>
```

In the case above this references the file with a name of "file".